# External Dns registers private ip with cloudflare instead of public ip

Tags: kubernetes, cloudflare, rancher, argocd, external-dns

After deploying External-Dns to our K8 cluster using official Helm bitnami/external-dns chart dns records are created in cloudflare but the ip address regitered are private and not public ip. Due to this my certificate generation with cert-manager also fails.

Helm chart: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/external-dns
Values.yaml for helm chart

```
## Modify how DNS records are synchronized between sources and providers (options: sync, upsert-only)
##
policy: sync

logLevel: debug

domainFilters:
- example.xyz

## Configure resource requests and limits
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
##
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 50m
    memory: 50Mi
  requests:
    memory: 50Mi
    cpu: 10m

## If specified, the pod's tolerations.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
##
tolerations:
- key: "infra"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "true"
  effect: "NoSchedule"

## Cloudflare configuration to be set via arguments/env. variables
##
cloudflare:
  ## `CF_API_TOKEN` to set in the environment
  ##
  apiToken: "NOJNFOJNOSJNOMSPKPLMPMP"
  ## `CF_API_EMAIL` to set in the environment
  ##
  email: "devops@example.xyz"
  ## Enable the proxy feature of Cloudflare
  ##
  proxied: false
```

Once this is deployed, I can see in the logs that the records are getting created but private ip and not public ip.
logs

```
time="2022-01-20T09:55:31Z" level=debug msg="Endpoints generated from ingress: devops-gitops/argo: [argo.example.xyz 0 IN A  10.1.0.2;10.1.0.3;10.1.0.4;10.244.0.1 [] argo.example.xyz 0 IN A  10.1.0.2;10.1.0.3;10.1.0.4;10.244.0.1 []]"
time="2022-01-20T09:55:31Z" level=debug msg="Endpoints generated from ingress: devops-gitops/test: [test.example.xyz 0 IN A  10.1.0.2;10.1.0.3;10.1.0.4;10.244.0.1 [] example.xyz 0 IN A  10.1.0.2;10.1.0.3;10.1.0.4;10.244.0.1 []]"
time="2022-01-20T09:55:31Z" level=debug msg="Endpoints generated from ingress: ingress-nginx/test1: [test1.example.xyz 0 IN A  10.1.0.2;10.1.0.3;10.1.0.4;10.244.0.1 [] example.xyz 0 IN A  10.1.0.2;10.1.0.3;10.1.0.4;10.244.0.1 []]"
```

The ingress are created from Rancher->Cluster->Service-Discovery->Ingress.
And external-dns is deployed in a new namespace created for `extenral-dns` and `cert-manager`

Kubernetes cluster is deployed in Rancher

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: @MikolajS.
Rancher version: v2.6.3 and K8s version: v1.22.5

Comment: I found out that my `ingress-nginx` was exposing an ingress for private IPs.
Since I'm using hetzner cloud, I had to add this annotation on my ingress-nginx: `load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/disable-private-ingress: "true"`

Answer (score 0):

External DNS will use whatever IP is generated on the service. If you have mapped an internal IP on the service, External DNS will use that on its DNS updates.